# Send number without reloading whatsapp web page

Tags: c#, selenium, whatsapp

I'm doing some automations with Whatsapp Web using selenium, to send the messages I'm using a click-send-api that WhatsApp is available

https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55555text=MESSEGE

Using this url, every time I pass a new number and message and send via selenium to Chrome, the page is reloaded.
This approach works, but with every number I have to reload the page ..

I have seen several similar softwares that once downloaded the Whatsapp Web page
they can open a new conversation (with a number that is not in the calendar) without reloading the page .. I believe this is done by javascript ..
I researched several ways, tried everything but I could not ..

Anyone have any tips on how this is done?

Comment: Can you share your code, thanks

Comment: my code is being done via click normally by selenium, every message number I reload the url with the number and message
Is there any way to re-upload the URL https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+Number again & again, for sending message to every new phone number ...? Like injecting javascript or anything else?

Comment: I can't really understand what you mean. It is obvious that you are doing it in selenium, I just want to see your code and html code or screen.

Comment: @TroyChuck stuck in same issue. if you find any solution please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Use WhatsApp Desktop App

1.Load Url in Web

2.if Browser Connect With Application, App Automatic Load New Chat With Shared Url

3.Just Handel Click {ENTER} in your Code for Send Pm To Client

Every 1 Min Can Send 12-15 Message To Clients